# what is infinte decent

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $$a^6+2b^6=4c^6$$,then prove that $$a=b=c=0$$
For solving this problem,at first, let $(a,b,c)$ be the smallest solution of that equation.
But why at first taken such as. What is the method to prove this method.
Can anyone please explain me about this method from basic to details?

Comment: Hm, what's the connection between the title and the question?  Could you make that more clear please?

Comment: have you saw this here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent

Comment: As I can judge by your title, you wonder if a descent proof is a decent proof ?

Comment: Many website used infinite decent to proof this problem.But i dont know what is infinite decent.So i want to understand infinite decent using this example.

Comment: Counteexample: $a=1,b=1,c=\sqrt[6]{3/4}$.

Comment: @barakmanos Pretty sure $a,b,c$ are supposed to be integers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One of the important properties of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is that [it is well-ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle); that is, any nonempty subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ of the natural numbers has a smallest element. So to prove that a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is empty, you can show that it doesn't have a smallest element. One way of doing this is to suppose $A$ has a smallest element $a_0 \in A$, and find another element $a \in A$ with $a < a_0$. This would contradict the assumption that $a_0$ was smallest, so then $A$ must be empty.

A closely related idea is [proof by infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent). Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, and suppose that given any element $a \in A$, you can always find a smaller element. Then, if $A$ is nonempty, picking any $a_0 \in A$ produces an infinite descending sequence $a_0 > a_1 > a_2 > \ldots$ of natural numbers. But such a sequence can't exist, because there must be a smallest element of the sequence. (This is equivalent to $\mathbb{N}$ being well-ordered.)

For this problem, say, let $A = \{ a \in \mathbb{N} : a > 0 \text{ and } a^6 + 2b^6 = 4c^6 \text{ for some } b,c \}$, and suppose it has a smallest element $a_0$. Then you can find a smaller positive natural number $a < a_0$ that also is in a solution of the equation. But this contradiction shows that $A$ had to be empty; that is, $a^6 + 2b^6 = 4c^6$ must have no solutions with positive $a$. (You still would need to eliminate the possibility of $0 + 2b^6 = 4c^6$ for nonzero b or c, possibly by a similar argument, and also handle the case of negative $a$.)